# Python to access Azure DevOps secret password value

Tags: python, azure

Azure DevOPS (Linux OS) has variable SQL_PASSWORD with value xxxxxx.
I am passing command line arguments to Python script in azure pipeline like below:
python3 test.py $SQL_URL $SQL_USER $SQL_PASSWORD

I am trying to fetch inside test.py these environment variable values like:

```
import os
url=os.environ.get('SQL_URL')
uid=os.environ.get('SQL_USER')
passwd=os.environ.get('SQL_PASSWORD')

print(url)
print(uid)
print(passwd)
```

I am getting correct values for url and uid variables but for passwd getting value: **None**

Could you please advise me on how to fetch a correct value for passwd from Azure DevOps secret variable?

Thanks,
Naikum

Comment: SQL_PASSWORD != SQL_PASSWD?

Comment: sorry, edited typo. $SQL_PASSWORD env variable is passing to python script.

Comment: Passing them in as command line arguments vs passing them in the environment aren’t the same

Comment: Passing as command-line arguments to python script

Comment: DevOps masks secret variables from printing to the console. I'm not 100% sure if it keeps track of the chain of transformations, but it looks like from your case that it won't allow you to print it after it's passed to something else.